# -long and -notlong resources in Android not showing for 16:9 device

Tags: android, android-resources, android-screen-support

I am trying to use a different resource for 16:9 and 16:10 screens.

According to the sources, I can use

`drawable-notlong` for anything narrower than 3:5, and
`drawable-long` for anything wider.

However, when I place different drawables into these folders, I am seeing the `-notlong` version on a Nexus 5 (with a 16:9 aspect ratio, which is wider and I assume should therefore obtain its resources from the `-long` folder).

Is there anything obvious I have missed in the folder naming? I have also tried `drawable-notlong-land` and `drawable-notlong-nodpi` with the same effect.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I am facing same issue

Comment: I solved this by manually calculating the aspect ratios using the screen size.